# How do I change the volume of a PCM audio stream in node?

Tags: node.js, audio, stream, signal-processing, pcm

I am trying to figure out how to adjust the volume level of a PCM audio stream in node.

I have looked all over npmjs.org at all of the modules that I could find for working with audio, but haven't found anything that will take a stream in, change the volume, and give me a stream out.

Are there any modules that exist that can do this, perhaps even even something that wasn't made specifically for it?
If not, then I could create a module, if someone can point me in the right direction for modifying a stream byte by byte.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
I am writing a program to receive several PCM audio streams, and mix them for several outputs with varying volume levels. Example:

```
inputs       vol    output

music        25%    output 1 
live audio   80%    output 1
microphone    0%    output 1

music       100%    output 2 
live audio    0%    output 2
microphone    0%    output 2
```

Comment: convert the bytes to samples within a range of -1 to 1. now just multiply them with a factor in the range from 0 to 1.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to figure that part out, the part I am having trouble with is actually modifying the buffers... :/

Answer (score 0):

What type of connection are you using? (Would make it easier to give example code)

What you basically want to do, is create a connection. Then on the connection or request object add a listener for the 'data' event. If you don't set an encoding, the data parameter on the callback should be a [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). The data event is triggered after each chunk is delivered through the network.

The Buffer gives you byte-size access to the data-stream using regular javascript number values. You can then parse that chunk, keep them in memory over multiple data-events using a closure (in order to buffer multiple chunks). And when appropriate write the parsed and processed data to a socket (another socket or the same in case of bi-directional sockets). Don't forget to manage your closure in order to avoid memory leaks!

This is just an abstract description. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, guess I missed the email about a response. :/

Comment: The audio streams will be coming from several sources, mp3 files, and streamed live from an audio input card. Ideally, I would just pipe it through something that has a volume property that I can control...

A good example would be:
 [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/6eDfBtz2)